# Session variables in action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an action filter checks whether or not a session variable `ID` is set. For development purposes, I have manually set this variable prior to the check.

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {

            context.HttpContext.Session.Add("ID", 123123);

            int ID = (int)context.HttpContext.Session.Contents["ID"];
            var rd = context.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;

            TED _db = new TED();

            //if not in DB
            if (_db.Users.Find(ID) == null && rd.GetRequiredString("action") != "NoAccess")
            {
                RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "NoAccess");
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Home");
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("area", "");

                context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
            }

            base.OnActionExecuted(context);
        }
    }
```

As far as I understand, this code is run prior to any page, this `Session["ID"]` is always set. The site works fine if I am consistently testing, but it seems to break if I leave it for a while then try to continue testing. Here is the error I get:

```
int UserID = (int)Session.Contents["ID"];
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Initially I thought the session may simply be expiring, but prior to any page loading, `Session["ID"]` should be getting set. What is the issue here?

Comment: "but prior to any page loading, Session["ID"] should be getting set"--why don't you set a breakpoint and find out for sure

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you're implementing your actionfilter's on `OnActionExecuted` method which executes AFTER your action method

You should implement the `OnActionExecuting` method

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {

            context.HttpContext.Session.Add("ID", 123123);

            int ID = (int)context.HttpContext.Session.Contents["ID"];
            var rd = context.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;

            TED _db = new TED();

            //if not in DB
            if (_db.Users.Find(ID) == null && rd.GetRequiredString("action") != "NoAccess")
            {
                RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "NoAccess");
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Home");
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("area", "");

                context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doh! It's the smallest things that get you sometimes... Also, I edited your answer to change these lines:
`public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutedContext context)`
`base.OnActionExecuted(context);`
To say `Executing` also

Comment: always the small things that kill! big ones are easy to find.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile! The method signature is wrong.

Comment: @dvallejo, I guess you missed the point of my answer. I didn't really scan OP's code. I simply pointed out the part that I was clearly wrong. I assumed the rest worked. The signature and compilation doesn't have anything to do with OP using the wrong override.

Comment: I am unable to use this approach in .netcore, I am getting `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type iSession` . What can I do?

Comment: @Mwas, this should technically be posted as a new question pertaining to **.NET Core**, but to answer your question, in Core, the new filter should inherit from the **IActionFilter** interface